# setting levels apriori when using factorize in Pandas to cover missing cases

Tags: python, pandas, levels, categorical-data

I understand how to use factorize to encode levels of a factor, such as "L" and "W" (for wins and loses) into numeric values, such as "0" and "1":

```
import pandas as pd
first_df = pd.DataFrame({'outcome': ["L", "L", "W", "W"]})
pd.factorize(first_df['outcome'])
```

The above returns `(array([0, 0, 1, 1]), array(['L', 'W'], dtype=object))`.

However, later on, I'd like to combine this result with some other results, where we now have a new outcome, a draw ("D"), and here is where things get sticky:

```
second_df = pd.DataFrame({'outcome': ["L", "L", "D", "D"]})
pd.factorize(second_df['outcome'])
```

This returns `(array([0, 0, 1, 1]), array(['L', 'D'], dtype=object))`

I need some way to preemptively declare the fact that there are 3 different levels when I create the dataframes, and map the correct numeric value to the correct level. How can I achieve this?

Comment: direct factorization should only be necessary when categories don't matter ; almost always just use a Categorical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this is definitely possible using a `Categorical`:

```
outcome_cat = pd.Categorical(
    first_df['outcome'], 
    categories=['L', 'W', 'D'], ordered=False
)
```

The semantics of `Categorical`s may not be exactly the same as the output of `pd.factorize()`, but the `codes` attribute contains your data as numeric values, it's just that the `Categorical` is also aware of the unobserved `'D'` value:

```
outcome_cat.codes
Out[6]: array([0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int8)
```